# DBxmys.dll missing error for dbexpress

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I'm working on Delphi XE2 and mysql and dbexpress components

i have this code

```
 StrQu:='select * from mytable'; //my actual query is place here
 DM.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
 DM.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(StrQu);
 DM.SQLQuery1.open;  //i get the error here
```

[image]

Thouugh the Dll is present `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0` directory
i tried copying the dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin` directory also but same error.
any one know to solve this problem>?

Comment: If directory mentioned is seen by CMD>PATH, it might be the version is not correct or other files missing/wrong. The message is allways raised if a dll could not be loaded (missing is only one of the possebilities)  http://reportman.sourceforge.net/doc/openingdatatrouble.html  or http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/36575

Comment: Run SysInternals ProcessMonitor and track file accesses - check in which folders your program tried and failed to find 1) DBXpress configurations 2) dbxmys driver  You may start [here](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2010/11/dbx-without-deploying-dbxdrivers-ini/) to read how DBXpress searches for its configuration and files locations

Comment: You have to put that dll in a path accessible to your program in runtime, for example the system path, the same path where your exe is stored or a folder registered in the path environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Set TSQLConnection LibraryName property to dbxmys.dll. You might also need to set VendorLib property to some other DLL. All DLLs must be accessible to your program in runtime, e.g. place it in the same folder as is your *.exe. Also, make sure those are compatible (don't mix 32-bit vs 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

In your delphi version search for tools>options>enviroment variables, so look to variable Path and put the directory of your dll "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin". This happend with me when I installed OpenSSH. I don't know why.